# Filenotfounderror File b'.csv' does not exist

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\khalha\Desktop\AllSalesForecasting')


dataframe12 = pd.read_csv('54.csv')
june18 = pd.read_csv('54.csv', index_col="Customer")

print(june18)
```

Even if I dont have the last 2 lines, I am recieveing an error:

> FileNotFoundError: File b'54.csv' does not exist

I have no idea why this is happening for I have done many problems using this format, but now it does not seem to work.

Comment: try to give the absolute path to `.csv` files

Comment: @DrutaRuslan I tried it and it does not work. Is there anything else that could be causing this issue?

Comment: Works fine for me, are you 100% positive the file exists?

Comment: @tgikal I have posted an image of my folder as an answer, I dont see whats wrong

Comment: which python version? 2.7?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 python 3.6

Comment: Just for the heck of it rename your file on the OS and in your script to `'x.csv'`. I'm going to to make a wild guess that the `'-' ` in your current filename isn't really a hyphen. If this works my guess is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error simply existed because I named my file 52.csv, 53.csv, 54.csv, etc. I dropped the .csv when I named them, and it worked fine. (I thought because we are reading 54.csv for example, you have to label the file name as so, when in reality you read it as 54.csv, simply because it is a csv file)

Comment: What did you mean by that? Did you use pd.read_csv('data') to read the file data.csv? Is that it?

Answer (score 2):

unicode error can be solved by using double slash instead of single slash .This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of getting error message File

> b'G:\Tensorflow_tutorial_karim\test.csv' not found.

After searching many links could not get any satisfying reply and neither could pd.read_csv(filename) worked.

I tried with spider I-python console after pasting the test.csv file in C:\workingDirectory. It gave the error message

> "SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes
>   in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escapeto the effect'cannot
>   decode escape characters".

Taking the clue, I replaced back slash('\') with forward slash ('/')in path and it worked fine.

With this, Jupyter note book also reads the files without any problem.Hope it will work for others also.